# Check for subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, files

A)I used the following code to get the modified date of a file. But this is also selecting the subdirectories and thus returning an error. How van I fix this.

```
for file in $1/*; do
        echo `stat -c %y $file | cut -d ' ' -f1`
done
```

$1 is the directory I am passing

B) Also is there any way to do this thing. That I need to pass a directory and date range as commandline argument and list the file and modified date which lies in this date range.
Eg `output.sh /home/user/desktop 2014-10-07 2014-11-17` should list all the files in this directory which are modified in this time intervel

Comment: Cross-posted on AU: http://askubuntu.com/questions/548187/shell-script-to-check-for-subdirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all files in directory `$1` that are older than 1000 minutes and younger than 2000 minutes:

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +1000 -mmin -2000
```

If you want to search recursively into subdirectories, remove `-maxdepth 1`.

If you prefer to specify time in integral days, rather than minutes, use `-mtime`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +20 -mtime -26
```

#### Loop over files while skipping directories

`-d` can be used to test for directories and `continue` will skip over them:

```
for file in "$1"/*; do
    [ -d "$file" ] && continue
    echo $(stat -c %y $file | cut -d ' ' -f1)
done
```